# Which object "holds" addEventListener?

Tags: javascript

For reasons, I'm looking for the source object that defines `addEventListener`. Starting from `XMLHttpRequest`, I've discovered the following:

```
> Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty(XMLHttpRequest.prototype, 'addEventListener')
false

> XMLHttpRequest.prototype.__proto__
XMLHttpRequestEventTarget {}

> Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty(XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.prototype, 'addEventListener')
false

> XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.prototype.__proto__
EventTarget {}

> Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty(EventTarget.prototype, 'addEventListener')
false

> EventTarget.prototype.__proto__
Object {}
```

How is it possible? `addEventListener` doesn't seem to be defined in any prototype.

To be clear, I know that this function is a native function, but what I don't understand is how, from a standard point of view, the property isn't available from any prototype but still there when we need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DOM *interfaces* are complicated. They are specified as an interface ([`EventTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget) in this case), but the methods have to be implemented on each "class" or prototype separately because JS doesn't have multiple inheritance or interfaces. The exact inheritance hierarachy may vary between browsers and their versions though.

In your example, `addEventListener` is actually implemented on the `XMLHttpRequest` prototype (at least in my Opera), only you were checking it wrong:

```
// Opera 12
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.hasOwnProperty("addEventListener") // true
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(XMLHttpRequest.prototype,  "addEventListener") // true
//                              ^^^^
Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf(XMLHttpRequest.prototype) // true - flat hierarchy

// Chrome 48
EventTarget.prototype.hasOwnProperty("addEventListener") // true
XMLHttpRequest.prototype instanceof EventTarget // true - some indirection
```

Comment: _JS doesn't have multiple inheritance or interfaces_..... is key note here, i guess.

Answer (score 0):

**EventTarget** prototype holding that property:

```
console.log(EventTarget.prototype.hasOwnProperty('addEventListener'))
// true
```

Take o look on  [Mozilla MDN: EventTarget.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

> The EventTarget.addEventListener() method registers the specified
>   listener on the EventTarget it's called on.

From [Mozilla MDN: EventTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget)

> EventTarget is an interface implemented by objects that can receive
>   events and may have listeners for them.
>
> **Element**, **document**, and **window** are the most common event targets, but
>   other objects can be event targets too, for example XMLHttpRequest,
>   AudioNode, AudioContext, and others.
>
> **Methods**
>
> EventTarget.addEventListener() Register an event handler of a specific
>   event type on the EventTarget. 
>   ..........
>   ..........

So addEventListener could be called on all interfaces which inherits properties from EventTarget interface( [window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window), [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document), [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) etc.).

Comment: answering  to "Which object “holds” addEventListener?"  question, could you explain me what's wrong here, maybe i didn't catch it ... (